# How to evaluate a member inside a hash that is a list

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I've the following Hash (dummy{}) with one member being an array, how do I build a code logic to:
(a) evaluate each Key -> Value 
(b) evaluate each Key -> values(s) (if it is an array inside a Hash)

```
dummy  = { :a1 => "xyz",
           :b1 => ["xyz1", "ayz2", "xyz3", "xyz4"] }
```

The code I've for a Key with just one value is:

```
eval(dummy)[a1.to_sym]
```

I need a clean way to evaluate a hash member that has multiple values in an array.

Here is the IRB output:

```
1.9.3-p327 :002 > dummy  = { :a1 => "xyz",
1.9.3-p327 :003 >                :b1 => ["xyz1", "ayz2", "xyz3", "xyz4"] }
=> {:a1=>"xyz", :b1=>["xyz1", "ayz2", "xyz3", "xyz4"]}
```

Now I can access the members and their Key-Value pairs (in a very simple way as below:)

```
1.9.3-p327 :005 > pp dummy[:a1.to_sym]
"xyz"
=> "xyz"
1.9.3-p327 :006 > pp dummy[:b1.to_sym][0]
"xyz1"
=> "xyz1"
1.9.3-p327 :007 > pp dummy[:b1.to_sym][1]
"ayz2"
=> "ayz2"
1.9.3-p327 :008 > pp dummy[:b1.to_sym][2]
"xyz3"
=> "xyz3"
1.9.3-p327 :009 > pp dummy[:b1.to_sym][3]
"xyz4"
=> "xyz4"
```

Now, I need a "generic" ruby code that takes care of both the above situations to access the members and their values - note: for example, I only selected 1 and 4 values, but in reality my need is where the values range from 1000 - 5000

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to perform and the expected output?

Comment: I'm trying to create a configuration file which has a unique Hash map for each project. You can think of replacing "dummy" with "project1" and "a1" with the type of destination servers (IP - Addresses).

Comment: not sure about point - a and point -b. please clear it .

Comment: I really don't know what you're trying to achieve. Can you amend your question to include sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making sure everything is an Array allows for uniform treatment:

```
dummy  = { :a1 => "xyz",
           :b1 => ["xyz1", "ayz2", "xyz3", "xyz4"] }

dummy.each do |k, v|
  Array(v).each do |element| #Array(v) puts v in an Array, unless it already is an array.
    puts element
  end
  puts
end
```

Comment: are you sure? did you get the op's need? i m still confused.